# COFF byte ordering in PE formatted executable

Tags: windows, coff

I have a hexdump of a Windows binary and identified the COFF header in this executable by looking at the COFF offset:

```
0000080: 4550 0000 014c 0003 6ec8 3add 0000 0000
0000090: 0000 0000 00e0 010f 010b 0301 2000 0000
```

We can further verify this is the file header because of its [4 byte signature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680547(v=vs.85).aspx#signature__image_only_): `'PE'` followed by two `NULL` bytes. Clearly, the format appears to be expressed in little endian because if we were to write PE explicitly, we would have the hex `50 45`.

If we look at [the PE format specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680547(v=vs.85).aspx#ms-dos_stub__image_only_) and carry this observation though, the `NumberOfSections` field (offset 2 bytes from the end of the signature that are skipped for the `Machine` field), we determine there are 768 sections (`03 00` in little endian). This contradicts the spec, stating that the Windows loader limits the number of sections to 96.

Furthermore, byte ordering in the `Timestamp` field (next 4 bytes) seems odd because only the permutation `3add 6ec8` produces a Unix timestamp that is in the past.

Is there a more explicitly defined byte ordering that I'm missing? Why do the byte orderings between the fields seem inconsistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hexdump is using a misleading format.  Try again with byte format (`-c` option)

In the dump you have, the output is already byte swapped.  Things appear in the order

> (byte1)(byte0) ' ' (byte3)(byte2) ' ' (byte5)(byte4) ' '

and so on.

The PE header is, as you mentioned

> 50 45

Hexdump's default display rules take these two bytes and interpret them as a 16-bit little endian integer, 0x4550, which is why the display is `4550`

The number of sections is 3, (`03 00` in the file).  I don't know why you said `03 00` is 768 in little endian because that's just wrong.  In this case, the 16-bit LE default format of hexdump actually worked because it is a 16-bit field, the decode of 0x0003 is correct.

The timestamp is displayed as `6ec8 3add` but the actual bytes in the file are `c8 6e dd 3a`.  Now the 32-bit field size and the 16-bit hexdump format mismatch, leading to your total confusion.

Comment: Would that mean `0003` from the hexdump be actually expressed as `03 00`? If so, I think that's more linked sections than an executable can have. 3 seems much more reasonable, but I'm not sure.

Comment: The actual bytes that appear in the file, `03 00`, is little-endian for 3.  Not 768.

Comment: @JamesTaylor: Your problem is that you're trying to swap what hexdump has already swapped, but not keeping track of the number of swaps.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Thank you!